# What does atop 'cache' output really mean?

Tags: linux, memory, cache

The [atop man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/atopv) says:

> An occupation percentage of 90% is considered 'critical'. Notice that
>   this occupation percentage is the accumulated memory consumption of
>   the kernel (including slab) and all processes; *the memory for the page
>   cache ('cache' and 'buff' in the MEM-line) is not implied*!

The `MEM` line of our atop output looks like this:

`MEM | tot    94.4G | free  252.4M  | cache  70.1G |dirty 127.5M  | buff  450.4M | slab    4.5G`

I am trying to understand what the 70.1G of cache really refers to.  One person I spoke with said it includes process virtual memory.  However, when I searched for information on [Linux Page Cache](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Linux_Page_Cache_Basics#Memory_Usage), I saw this:

> Under Linux, the Page Cache accelerates many accesses to files on non
>   volatile storage

which makes it sounds like it is really I/O storage related.  In looking at virtual memory used by all the processes, I see about 70G allocated/used, which seems to correlate with the 70G from the atop output.

So is atop showing virtual memory usage, memory cache reserved for speeding file access (or maybe both)?